# How to convert a pointer to an IObjectiveC interface?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

This interface is declared in the delphi source code:

```
  UILayoutSupport = interface(IObjectiveC)
    ['{2A1B5C8A-57CE-4423-A857-6BD6BCC61F77}']
    function length: CGFloat; cdecl;
  end;
```

now in delphi we have also this function:

```
UIViewController = interface(UIResponder)
  ...
  function topLayoutGuide: Pointer; cdecl;
end;
```

from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621367-toplayoutguide?language=objc we see that topLayoutGuide return an UILayoutSupport.

now How can I convert a **pointer** that i get from topLayoutGuide to an **UILayoutSupport**?

Comment: I'd just like to know why the downvoter did so - I see nothing at all wrong with this question

Comment: Simply type-cast, eg: `var LS: UILayoutSupport; Pointer(LS) := VC.topLayoutGuide;` or `var LS: UILayoutSupport; LS := UILayoutSupport(VC.topLayoutGuide);`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I already tried it, it's not work with IObjectiveC interface :(

Comment: @loki "*it's not work*" - in what way exactly? You need to be more specific.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've spoken to loki personally - it throws an AV. Sorry there's no more info - he's likely asleep :-)

Comment: Objective-C protocol is not compatible with Delphi interface, it has to be wrapped. Answer is somewhere in Macapi.ObjectiveC unit. TOCGenericImport<>.Wrap is most likely candidate, but you would need to declare appropriate class. there are also WrapInterface and WrapObjectiveCReturn functions. I haven't used iOS in Delphi long enough to be sure and I don't think I even needed to wrap something that was not predefined.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar yes actually I need to declare some class around UILayoutSupport to be able to call Wrap. it's a little "heavy". I will take a look at WrapObjectiveCReturn but also heavy to use it.